# binding tooltip to custom dependency property

Tags: xaml, binding, customproperty

this code work correct:

```
   <UserControl x:Class="Extended.InputControls.TextBoxUserControl" 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Extended.InputControls">
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox"
            ToolTip="{Binding Path=CustomToolTip,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:TextBoxUserControl}}"/>
</UserControl>
```

but this code Does not work!!!

```
<UserControl x:Class="Extended.InputControls.TextBoxUserControl" 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Extended.InputControls">
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox">
            <TextBox.ToolTip>
                <ToolTip Text="{Binding Path=CustomToolTip,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:TextBoxUserControl}}" Background="Yellow"/>
            </TextBox.ToolTip>
        </TextBox>
</UserControl>
```

i need create custom tooltip and bind it to CustomToolTip but in second code that's not bind to anything
where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if we're talking WPF here, it should be `<ToolTip Content="...">` instead of `<ToolTip Text="...">`, since `ToolTip` has no `Text` property.

Regarding the binding: Binding to other elements in the user control from within a ToolTip doesn't work since ToolTip elements are not part of the visual tree, as explained in [another question that also provides one potential solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24141331/bind-to-wpf-custom-control-dependency-property-for-tooltip?rq=1).

However, it seems that you're binding to some property defined in the UserControl's code-behind? In that case it's even easier to solve by setting the UserControl's `DataContext` to the control itself:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Extended.InputControls.TextBoxUserControl" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Extended.InputControls"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox">
        <TextBox.ToolTip>
            <ToolTip Content="{Binding CustomToolTip}" Background="Yellow"/>
        </TextBox.ToolTip>
    </TextBox>
</UserControl>
```

Alternatively, you could also set the `DataContext` in code-behind:

```
public TextBoxUserControl()
{
    this.DataContext = this;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

In both cases, the `CustomToolTip` property can be accessed directly without the need for a `RelativeSource` binding.

An even better solution would be to introduce come kind of Viewmodel class that holds the `CustomToolTip` and all similar properties, and set this class as the UserControl's `DataContext`.